# OBJ File only has color when in my documents folder?

Tags: color, 3d-printing, obj

I am trying to 3D print a model at my local library, and need to have an OBJ file of my model. When I export it, the OBJ file only shows color when it and the MTL file are in my laptop's documents folder. When I export it anywhere else, it is completely gray. I even make sure to have the MTL file with it. What do I do?

Here are pictures of it when I open it from my documents folder, and it when I open it from anywhere else.

[image: After opening from the "Documents" folder]

[image: After opening from anywhere else]

Comment: Does it have textures?

Comment: The first thing I think of is that the MTL file is using global paths to find textures. Are there textures? What happens if they are in the Documents folder but everything else (or just the obj file) isn’t?

Comment: It only has colors using nodes.

Comment: I came home from school today and it was fixed, how strange.